# What is the decay of the convolution of these two slowly decaying functions?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, approximation-theory

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}^{-\alpha}$, and $g(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}^{-\beta}$ for some $\alpha, \beta > 0$ satisfying $\alpha + \beta >1$.

Then let $$(f * g)(y) := \int _{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha/2} (1+(x-y)^2)^{\beta/2}} dx~.$$

For all fixed $y$ the above integral converges, thanks to $\alpha+\beta >1$, but we don't assume $f, g \in L^1$, only $fg \in L^1$.

How to prove the decay rate of $f*g$ ?

I suspect it's something like $O(y^{-\min(\alpha,\beta)})$. Thanks

EDIT: Thanks to the calculation of reuns, I also wonder what is the answer in the case where $\alpha = 1$, $\beta >0$ ? ! Thanks

Comment: For $a\in (0,1)$ it is not $y^{-\min(a,b)}$ because for $r < 1$, $\int_1^\infty y^{-a} (x+y)^{-b}dy \ge \int_1^{x^r} y^{-a}x^{-b}(1+y/x)^{-b}dx$ $=x^{-b} \int_1^{x^r} y^{-a}(1+O(x^{r-1}))dy\sim  \frac1{1-a} x^{-b} x^{r-ar}$

Comment: thanks reuns, Does your calculation adapt well to the case $a=1$ ?

Comment: Sure, just follow the same lines